# Setting up events for separate classes

Tags: c#, events

I have a class `Character`, that stores 3 `CharacterAttribute` classes. What I want is that at a certain point `Character` would do something if an event is raised within one of the `CharacterAttribute` classes.

```
class Character
{
    public CharacterAttribute Physical;

    public Character Create(...) 
    {
        Physical = new CharacterAttribute();
        Physical.SkillPointGained += this.OnSkillPointGained(); 
        // ERROR: cannot convert void to System.EventHandler
    }

    public void OnSkillPointGained()
    {
        // do stuff here after the event has been fired
    }
}

class CharacterAttribute
{
    public event EventHandler SkillPointGained;

    public void GainExperience(...)
    {
        SkillPointGained(this, new EventArgs()); // would raise the event here
    }
}
```

I get a "cannot implicitly convert void to System.EventHandler" error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two lines of code need to be fixed up a little bit.

```
public void OnSkillPointGained()
```

should read:

```
void OnSkillPointGained(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

And

```
Physical.SkillPointGained += this.OnSkillPointGained();
```

Should read:

```
Physical.SkillPointGained += this.OnSkillPointGained;
```

(...however I like the elegance of Marc's answer better.)

Comment: I prefer yours because with Marks approach you can’t unhook the event (unless you keep track of the delegate).

Comment: Thanks! funny that I tried both corrections; just not in the same time.

Answer (score 1):

`EventHandler` has the delegate signature of `void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)`. You are a: matching the wrong signature, and b: you're *invoking* the method rather than targeting the method as a delegate.

You can cheat, though:

```
Physical.SkillPointGained += delegate { this.OnSkillPointGained(); };
```

This creates an anonymous method that acts as the immediate handler, *drops* the sender/args, and invokes your `OnSkillPointGained` method.

Comment: Or you can change the event method signature to `public void OnSkillPointGained(object sender, EventArgs e)` and add the handler like `Physical.SkillPointGained += this.OnSkillPointGained;` to do it the "normal" way.

Comment: @NightOwl888 adding a public method with signature `object sender, EventArgs e` is nothing like normal :) But yes, you could add a *private* method like that, which calls the public parameterless method

Comment: (fixed up my answer accordingly)